# async/await Tcp socket implement accepts only one connection

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

I'm used to Begin/end APM pattern and i would like to update my socket server to .Net 4.5/async/await. I wrote an sample code from internet sources and it's not working.

I would like to have all the connected clients separated to own classes after they been accepted to connect **(not yet implemented..)**. The loop which accepts all incoming connections is running at own thread.

Basically Main.cs is the place where i accept client, create new class (Client.cs/Session.cs) for connection and point that accepted client to that class. Well, that is what i'm planning to do and its not in the code and the main problem currently are my knowledge of how to handle this accepting sequence and why i cant connect more than one client at the time ? I hope you can point me to correct answer.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Picture of server logic]

### Codes

**Form1.cs**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Own thread for accepting connections

            Main ConnectionLoop = new Main(10);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConnectionLoop.PrepareThread));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    public class Main
    {
        private int m_backLog = 0;

        // constructor
        public Main(int Backlog)
        {
            m_backLog = Backlog;
            Console.WriteLine("Main class created, backlog: {0}", Backlog);
        }

        public void PrepareThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread created");
            StartAccepting(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
        }

        private async Task StartAccepting(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started listening..");
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6112);
            listener.Start();
            await AcceptClientsAsync(listener, cts.Token);
            //  Thread.Sleep(600000);
        }

        private async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var clientCounter = 0;
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                clientCounter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} accepted!", clientCounter);
                await EchoAsync(client, clientCounter, token);
            }
        }

        private async Task EchoAsync(TcpClient client, int clientCounter, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (client)
            {
                var buf = new byte[4096];   // buffer for stream
                var stream = client.GetStream();    // stream itself

                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // some conditions we don't know is client connected, lets have timeout
                    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                    var amountReadTask = stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
                    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, amountReadTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
                    {
                        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client timed out");
                        await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        break;
                    }

                    var amountRead = amountReadTask.Result;
                    if (amountRead == 0) break; // end of stream
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, amountRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} disconnected", clientCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Async is for long running processes, and prevents unnecessary waiting on long running I/O bound processes. It *DOESN'T* provide any kind of concurrency whatsoever. It just frees up the CPU so it doesn't sit around waiting.

So you will need to utilize the rest of the TPL (Task Parallel Library) to provide the concurrency you need to allow simultaneous clients. Likely this means spinning off a Task for the client once the connection occurs, and using that Task to manage the client.

Async can compliment that by making sure each client doesn't block a full thread, but by itself async only helps you not block, it doesn't provide concurrency.

First off, I would like to strongly recommend reading all of the info over at MSDN about the TPL. It's alot, but it is good reading and will help immensely.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

As for a more concrete example, I can try.
In your loop where you accept clients, you will want to gain parallelism as soon as you have a connected client. This will enable your run loop to go back to accepting clients, and let the client still interact. So for example:

```
    private async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var clientCounter = 0;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            clientCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} accepted!", clientCounter);
            Task.Run(async () => await EchoAsync(client, clientCounter, token), token);
        }
    }
```

Note this is psuedo code. I didn't try compiling it. But the concept is solid.

If you have large amounts of clients you will need to be more specific than just using Task.Run, but for a sample it works fine. It will utilize Thread pool threads for the parallelism. Which works fine for at least 100, but can decrease in performance after that.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Would you like to give me rough example , even pseudo code for concurrent asynchronous socket ?

Answer (score 1):

An `async` function returns a task that is completed when that function completes.

In your `AcceptClientsAsync` function, you're `await`ing the `EchoAsync` function. This means that `AcceptTcpClientAsync` will not be called again until after `EchoAsync` completes (that is, after the cancellation token is signalled).

For an asynchronous socket server, you should have one task that only accepts in a loop, and for each connection, you should have a "processing" task. These have to be independent - you can't `await` the processing task from the accepting task.

**Update:** Adding example, as per request:

```
private async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken token)
{
    var clientCounter = 0;
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        clientCounter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Client {0} accepted!", clientCounter);
        var echoTask = EchoAsync(client, clientCounter, token);
        // TODO: save the echoTask in some kind of per-client data structure.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, can you give me an example ? This task & async/await is confusing me alot